# Transform vertical address list to horizontal list on Excel 2010

Tags: excel, list, excel-2010

A simple question, but one where i have found an answer to yet. I have a  large list of addresses in vertical format that i want to change to a horizontal list. Below is an example, basically i want to change the cells to read accross horizontal rather than down vertically, cell values for each section in brackets:

Vertical list:

```
(A1) 12 Norton Street
(A2) Warwick
(A3) Warwickshire
(A4) CV12 3SE
```

Horizontal list:

```
(A1) 12 Norton Street  (B1) Warwick  (C1) Warwickshire  (D1)CV12 3SE
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

I don't know excel 2010 but I can't imagine this has changed:

Select your vertical list of addresses, go to B1, use "Paste special" and check the "Transpose" checkbox to paste your values transposed. Delete column A afterwards.